java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl
Hi (excuse my english ... i'm french),
I've a problem with multi entityManager management in a springboot projet with hibernate 5.4.23.
I've created as many Persistent class as i have data base like this :
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
      entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManagerFactory",
      transactionManagerRef = "firstTransactionManager",
      basePackages = { "com.dao.first.repositories" }
)

public class PersistencefirstAutoConfiguration {
 
 @Primary
 @Bean(name = "firstDatasource")
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.first")
 public DataSource firstDataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
 }

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "firstPersistence")
 @Primary
 @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
// @Qualifier(value = "firstEntityManager")
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
      entityManagerFactory (
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("firstDatasource") DataSource firstDataSource
 ) {
  return builder
              .dataSource(firstDataSource)
              .packages("com.dao.first.entities")
              .persistenceUnit("firstPersistence")
              .build();
              
 }
 
 @Primary
 @Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
 public PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager (
             @Qualifier("firstEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
             firstEntityManagerFactory
      ) {
       return new JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
 }
 
 @Primary
 @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
 public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("firstDatasource") DataSource firstDataSource) {
  return new JdbcTemplate(firstDataSource);
 }
}

The first entitymanager has the @Primary tag but not the other ones.
Everything works fine but ....
In front I want to use the bootstrap table api, and I need to get the column name to create my table. (the nativequery is totally random and the bean are not mapped)
To do so i use the NativeQueryImpl class (I know it's deprecated but it's still working and there is nothing else) :
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "firstPersistence")
protected EntityManager firstEntityManager;
...
Query query = firstEntityManager.createNativeQuery(requestQuery);
ligneRequestListe = (List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>) query.getResultList();
NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query;
nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityOrderedMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

If the entitymanager used is the first one and has the @Primary tag, its' working just fine but if i use another entitymanager with no @Primary tag, i get an exception :
"java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl"
Any help / advise would be appreciated.

You are using unwrap to get the query, asign that to nativeQuery instead of casting as there might be some proxies going on. So do something like NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = query.unwrap(NativeQueryImpl.class) and then use that. However I don't get your code as you are setting the transformer twice, even after calling the result.

yes sorry it's an error, I was trying some stuff (like the unwrap : it send the same exception), i edit my code and remove this line. Thanks.

Please add the full stacktrace (and you should be using unwrap and not cast). I can see the casting to fail as proxies can be involved, the unwrap however should work.

Hello, sorry i was in Holidays. If i use unwrap or the cast, I have the same error : "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl"
